# MFC double buffering doesn't copy bitmap

Tags: c++, mfc

```
BOOL CPaintView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
    //return CPaintView::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
    return true;
}
void CPaintView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDC shadowMem;
    CBitmap shadowBit, *pOldBmp;
    CRect currWin;
    GetClientRect(currWin);

    shadowMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    shadowBit.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC,currWin.Width(), currWin.Height());
    pOldBmp = (CBitmap*)shadowMem.SelectObject(&shadowBit);
    shadowMem.FillSolidRect(0, 0, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height(), RGB(0, 255, 0));
    shadowMem.Rectangle(330, 300, 400, 500);

    pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height(), &shadowMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    shadowMem.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
}
```

The code is very simple and intuitive. I created a new CDC and a bitmap, set those to compatible to current CDC. Added new bitmap to new CDC. Then it fills the memory CDC to green color and draw a rectangle on it. then It copy the memory CDC's bitmap to current CDC.

And this is the result i got. You can clearly see a little green line draw near the top edge of the window. I'm not sure which part i messed up.

[image: result]

---

Update:

Thanks for all the help. I made some random adjustment of bitblt arguments and got a different result.

```
pDC->BitBlt(0, -400, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height(), &shadowMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

[image: update]

That -400 was a random number when i was trying to figure out the issue. It appears that when i copy the bitmap from shadowMem to pDC, somehow it doesn't match the coordinates correctly.

I couldn't find the reason yet, but if i copy this code to a new project, it works totally fine. I think i may have something to do with MM_ANISOTROPIC mode that my pDC is set to.

Comment: You are not selecting any `CBrush` and `CPen` into `shadowMem` before calling `Rectangle()`. What are you expecting `Rectangle()` to draw when you haven't defined what it should use for the line color and fill color? Is the hard-coded rect you specify to `Rectangle()` larger than your window's client area?  Notice the green doesn't actually span the entire client area width, which suggests it is getting drawn over. If you remove the `Rectangle()`, does your window then fill up completely with green?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thx for the response Remy. The rectangle is relatively small to the client area. So i expect to see a window with a green background and a white rectangle in it. The issue is when i copy the bitmap from shadowMem to pDC, somehow the coordinates don't map correctly. And to anwser you question, even if i remove the Rectangle() line, it doesn't show the green background neither. I think my current pDC is set to MM_ANISOTROPIC mode, i'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

As @RemyLebeau suggested in the comment, your `Rectangle` call probably isn't doing what you expect or want.

If we select a pen and brush, then draw a rectangle of (more or less) a size that's entirely inside the client area, we can see the result pretty easily. For example:

```
void CdoublebufferingView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDC shadowMem;
    CBitmap shadowBit, * pOldBmp;
    CRect currWin;
    GetClientRect(currWin);

    shadowMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    shadowBit.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height());
    pOldBmp = (CBitmap*)shadowMem.SelectObject(&shadowBit);
    shadowMem.FillSolidRect(0, 0, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height(), RGB(0, 255, 0));

    shadowMem.SelectObject(GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH));
    shadowMem.SelectObject(GetStockObject(WHITE_PEN));
    shadowMem.Rectangle(50, 50, currWin.Width() - 100, currWin.Height() - 100);
    pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, currWin.Width(), currWin.Height(), &shadowMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    shadowMem.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i don't think the pen was the issue. The problem is when i copy from shadowMem to pDC, the coordinates don't map correctly. The OnPrepareDC function changed current pDC to MM_ANISOTROPIC mode. I wonder if this has to do anything with it.

Comment: That would do it, MM_ANISOTROPIC lets you change the meaning of the coordinates. You would need to use coordinates that match your SetWindowExt and SetViewportExt.